# LoadError: Could not open library 'lzo2': lzo2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, centos, rake

When i run a command rake db:migrate on Centos 7 i get following error.
rake aborted!
LoadError: Could not open library 'lzo2': lzo2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
Could not open library 'liblzo2.so': liblzo2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

I am using ruby 2.3.0 and rails 5.0.1.

Comment: i have find the answer . i need to install following file.ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/7.3.1611/os/x86_64/Packages/lzo-devel-2.06-8.el7.i686.rpm

Answer (score 1):

Just install it:

```
yum install lzo-devel
```

Comment: No package liblzo2-dev available.
No package liblzo2-2 available.

Answer (score 0):

The following package is required for centos os.
yum install *lzo-devel*